# 3750 Temperatures for same rack

Tags: cisco, environmental-monitoring

I have 2 switches in the same rack AC room etc.

```
WS-C3750V2-48TS
TEMPERATURE is OK
Temperature Value: 41 Degree Celsius
Temperature State: GREEN
Yellow Threshold : 66 Degree Celsius
Red Threshold    : 76 Degree Celsius
```

VS

```
WS-C3750X-48P
SYSTEM TEMPERATURE is OK
System Temperature Value: 27 Degree Celsius
System Temperature State: GREEN
Yellow Threshold : 46 Degree Celsius
Red Threshold    : 60 Degree Celsius
```

How is this possible?  Anyone seen something like this before, Does a 3750V2 just run hot?

Comment: Have you eliminated rack placement as a possibility?  Hot air in a rack rises, some equipment in adjacement racks have right-to-left airflow, etc.  What's the relative position of these two switches to one another?  Different models can certainly have very different temp dynamics.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the warning/critical thresholds for these devices, this looks to be expected behavior as the 3750v2 has significantly higher settings.

Without delving into it in great detail, I would guess that the 3750X has the temp sensors at the airflow inlet and the 3750v2 has them at the outlet, possibly because IIRC the 3750X also has removable fan units and they didn't want to put the sensors in the fan units.

Comment: From 3750X environmental specifications, its operating range of temperature is between -5 ºC and 45 ºC. The  "Yello Threshold" is right at 46 ºC. This seems to confirm that 3750X temperature sensors are placed at the airflow inlet.

Answer (score 2):

The difference might simply be attributable to differing processing hardware or even temperature sensor locations.

Answer (score 0):

The 3750X also has extra air inlets above the ethernet ports. And it is a different platform, so quite possibly just has the sensor in a cooler location.